# GWT tree with checkbox:How to get all checked tree items?

Tags: gwt

I am using GWT 2.3.In my application I am using GWT Tree with check box.
Here is my code to create tree

```
formTree = new Tree();
                        if (formList != null && formList.size() > 0) {
                            for (Form form : formList) {
                                TreeItem item = new TreeItem(new CheckBox(form.getName()));
                                formTree.addItem(item);
                            }
                        }
```

In this tree I am using check box for every tree item. now on a  click of button I want all the checked tree items.I am not getting How can i get all the selected tree item.Please help me out.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest extending `TreeItem` to serve the actual purpose you're intending here: have it create *checkbox-based* item, which allows you to access the checkbox value. Currently, you'd have to loop through, get out the child of each, cast to the Checkbox class, then check the property. None of this is good practice, so extending it is really the only smart, efficient and effective way to go.

With that being said, here's how you might do it if you *really* had to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tree.getItemCount(); i++) 
{
    TreeItem item = tree.getItem(i); 
    CheckBox itemCheckBox = (CheckBox)item.getWidget();
    boolean checkBoxValue = itemCheckBox.getValue().booleanValue();
    // do something w/ checkBoxValue...
}
```