# SmartGWT: Checkbox Tree - the proper way to get selected checkbox value

Tags: smartgwt

SmartGWT has this property for a TreeGrid object:

```
employeeTreeGrid.setSelectionAppearance(SelectionAppearance.CHECKBOX);
```

This by default 'prepends' every nodes (including root) with checkbox.
(Just making myself clear.)

Also, I am aware of this similar solved question:
[GWT tree with checkbox:How to get all checked tree items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526725/gwt-tree-with-checkboxhow-to-get-all-checked-tree-items)

However, I do not seek this kind of solution..
What I'm looking for is a more efficient way, where I don't have to loop through 1000 items.

Is there any way to do this, if possible, using the widget I am using now?
If not, is there any other way, using other widget?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think as you use `SelectionAppearance.CHECKBOX` you tell to the grid that the selected records are marked by the checkbox field value. So every time you check one you select a record.
You can get the set of selected records by either `getSelection()` method or `getSelectedRecords(boolean)` because of deprecation of the previuous one.
You can have a look at the code of [this example of the smartgwt showcase](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_interaction_checkboxselect).